# Edit A Nested List In Scheme

Tags: list, optimization, runtime-error, scheme

I will keep this short and simple.

Want: To edit elements in a nested list. This nested list will have an unlimited number of elements but the list inside the list will always have 2 elements, like `(list (list 1 2) (list 3 4))`. I wanted to add a specific value 'x' to the first element of each nested list using recursion. e.g., `(change (list (list 1 2) (list 10 20) 3)`, where 3 is the 'x' value => `(list (list 4 2) (list 13 23))`

Code:

```
 (define (change lst x)
      (cond
        [(empty? lst) empty]
        [else (cons (+ (first (first lst)) x)  
(cons (second (first lst)) (change (rest lst) x)))]))
```

Output: an input such as `(change (list (list 12 2) (list 1 2)) 100)` will produce `(list 112 2 101 2)`.

Problem: The x value is added, but it should produce `(list (list 112 2) (list 101 2))`. Itt is not nested.

Comment: Examine the difference between `(cons 1 (cons 2 (list 3 4)))` and `(cons (list 1 2) (list 3 4))`. (This gets much more readable – and writable – if you write a seperate function for creating the new elements. And you should learn about `map`.)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
(define +n
  (lambda (n)
    (lambda (l)
      (fold-right
       (lambda (x a)
         (cons (+ (car x) n)
               (cons (cadr x)
                     a)))
       '()
       l ))))

(define 100+ (+n 100))
(100+ (list (list 12 2) (list 1 2)))
```